# In Flask, how can I write a condition in a file py (not html) and print only result in html?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, forms, flask

I'm new to Flask. In the `index.html` page, there are a `combobox` and a `textbox`. If I select the `Red` item of the combobox, I would like the textbox to print "`You have selected the item Red`".

[image]

I would like to achieve this inside in the python file and not in the html file. I saw that conditions can also be written in the html file, but I don't want to write them there. So I would like to write the condition in the `app.py` python file and **NOT** in the `index.html`. Something like this: `if colours.get() == "Red"`. Obviously, however, important, i would like to display the output in the textbox `index.html`

How can i get this? Thank you all!

**Flask Code: app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/combobox", methods=["GET","POST"])
def dropdown():
    colours = ["Red", "Blue", "Black", "Orange"]
    return render_template("index.html", colours=colours)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

**Textbox and combobox code: index.html**

```
  <form name="Item_1" action="/getLigand" method="POST">
    <select name="colours">
      {% for colour in colours %}
     <option value="{{ colour }}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>
      {% endfor %}     
   </select>
  </form>
  
<form action = "/result" method = "POST">
  <input type="text" name="result" />
  </form>
```

Comment: That's just not how it works.  Your HTML template MUST include all the components you want to display.  The Python code just provides things to fill in that template.  You can have something like `{{textbox}}` in your HTML and provide the whole HTML string in Python, but the HTML must have a placeholder to substitute.  Also, the code you're showing above doesn't have a "Submit" button.  Remember that your Python code only gets run when there is a new request -- either the initial request, or a form submission.

Comment: By the way, your current code will have SELECTED for every item.  That's not correct.  Only ONE item can be selected at a time.  Usually, you would provide the current selection as one of the template parameters, and have the code in your template choose which one gets SELECTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that works.  This is `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

colours = ["Red", "Blue", "Black", "Orange"]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", colours=colours, chosen="Black")

@app.route("/combobox", methods=["GET","POST"])
def dropdown():
    picked = request.form['colours']
    if picked == 'Red':
        message = "<<< You chose red"
    elif picked == 'Blue':
        message = "<<< You chose blue"
    elif picked == 'Black':
        message = "<<< You chose black"
    else:
        message = "<<< Oh no, you chose orange"

    return render_template("index.html", colours=colours, chosen=picked, message=message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

This is `templates/index.html`:

```
<form name="Item_1" action="/combobox" method="POST">
    <select name="colours">
      {% for colour in colours %}
        {% if colour == chosen %}
         <option value="{{ colour }}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>
        {% else %}
         <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
        {% endif %}     
      {% endfor %}     
   </select>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
  
<form action = "/result" method = "POST">
  <input type="text" name="result" value="{{ message }}" />
</form>
```

### Followup

Now, having written all that, I'm starting to wonder if you wanted that message to show up as soon as they PICK the color, without having to click a "Submit" button.  If that's what you're after, that can be done, but it's a very different technique.  That all has to be done in Javascript, as code that you embed within your HTML.  That's all handled entirely within the browser.  It doesn't send anything to the web server, so your Python code will not be involved.

Comment: There is a problem: I see in your code that there is no condition. In the textbox I wanted to display a different "message" for each color of the combobox, so I wanted to use the condition (if) as asked in the question, because I'll have to build other things based on the condition in the future. You used "message = "<< You chose " + chose" which automatically created the message. You were kind, but your answer is right, but that's not what I was looking for. Can I show me how I can create a condition (in the app.py file) and a different "message" for each color? Thank you

Comment: You already know how to do that.  You showed it in your question.  `if picked == 'Red':`.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this, otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question where I asked for help for an (if) condition. I've always used Python for desktop software, never for the web. I'm new to Python used for the web. I am learning now. I would really appreciate the help of an expert like you

Comment: There is nothing web-ish about this at all.  You're asking me how to write an `if` statement.  The key is that the variable `message` needs to contain whatever you want to appear in that text box.  So, just use the `if` statements you already know to assign a string to `message`.  That string gets passed to the template and substituted.

Comment: As you know, Flask is a web framework, so I'd say there's something web out there, especially for people like me who have just started learning Flask. It's easy for you, but not for those who have just started Flask. Can you edit your answer and show me what you said in the comment please? Being new to Flask, I'm not sure I understand. Thank you

Comment: IT'S NOT ABOUT FLASK.  The Flask stuff is already running there.  I have a statement that assigns a string to the variable `message`.  You want to assign a different string to `message` based on the value of the variable `picked`.  That's pure basic Python.  There is nothing about Flask in that task at all.

Comment: Okay, but I'm admitting to being difficulties, can you have the good heart to help me by editing your answer please? Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Just one curiosity: in the return of the index function, why did you write chosen="Black"? Why specify black color here? Thank you

Comment: Choose whatever you want to be selected by default.  I picked one at random.  If you don't want anything selected by default (which is valid), then pass an empty string.

Comment: Ok, i understand, thanks. I accepted your answer. Thanks again